# Should I say "innovative approach **to** making" or "innovative approach **in** making"?

Tags: meaning-in-context, prepositions

Prepositions, I tell you. While writing a blog, I stuck again in using them.

Here is a sentence I wrote:

> Siri’s integration for voice control shows company’s innovative approach ***in*** making revamped Apple TV more powerful and attractive.

But, 'Grammerly' shows an error and suggests me to use 'to' instead of 'in':

> Siri’s integration for voice control shows company’s innovative approach ***to*** making revamped Apple TV more powerful and attractive.

I am not sure about correctness of Grammerly's suggestion. I would like to know the difference of meaning while using these prepositions. Further, I would like to know my above sentence is correct or not with reasons.

If you will clear my doubts regarding use of preposition in this sentence, I will remain thankful to you.

Comment: Irrespective of this question, don't believe 'grammarly' all the time! :)

Comment: True Sir, that's why I ask this question here!

Comment: I wonder why the program didn't say anything about the missing article before *company's*. This, I think, gives us a hint how it may work.

Answer (score 1):

You can use both "approach to" and "approach in", but the difference I can think of is "approach to" is **more direct**.

In other words, "approach to something" often refers to a method or a way to ***do*** something:

> We need a whole new approach to the job.

However, "approach in *doing something*" often refers to a method or a way we apply that is ***necessary/relevant in doing something***:

> She took the wrong approach in her dealing with them.

In YOUR example, I believe both are almost equally correct, though I would give a slight edge to "approach to".